# Dynamic Dates in a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Is there any way that I can create a pivot table which only shows the previous 4 weeks data dynamically.

I can create a dates filter for this month or last month etc, but if I want to create the last 4 weeks I need to create an extra column in the data. If I do this, it shows the blanks in the pivot & If I exclude the blanks will this no longer be dynamic will it?

Thoughts.

Phil

Answer (score -1):

I would add in a helper column in the underlying data, using something like the if function. The if function should update automatically and you'll just need to refresh the pivot table.